# Can I have Groups in Dope Sheet?

Tags: dopesheet

Is there a way to make groups in Dope Sheet, so they can be collapsed, similar to the Scene collection?

I tried Ctrl+G on the dope sheet, it opens a prompt to add a name, but nothing happens.

[image]

It looks funny that you can collapse "Summary", but that collapses everything.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting a partial answer. But waiting to see if there is an alternative.

I can show only elements in a collection on the "Filter" dropdown.

[image]

It is not ideal because I want sometimes to compare the keyframes vs one in another collection. But this simplifies having a ton of elements in the viewport.